# Multibinding from Password box using prism Delegate Command

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, prism

I cannot seem to access these properties when using the password box, or any form of regular text control. I have set up a value converter, and it is returning the values correctly upon update, but once the command fires for my button, the params seem to be reset to null.

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="RegisterButton" Content="register" Height="28" Margin="0,0,8,8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FF005D99" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" FontSize="13.333" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" FontFamily="/Agile Project Management Tool 2012;component/Fonts/#Segoe UI" Padding="1,0,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="90" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ParamConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="EmailTextInput" Path="Text"/>
                <Binding ElementName="PhoneTextInput" Path="Text"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
```

**Value Converter**

```
  class TwoParamConverter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

**View Model**

```
    public ResigtrationViewModel()
    {
        _browsePicturesCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnBrowsePicturesCommand);
        _registerCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnRegisterCommand);
    }

    private void OnRegisterCommand(object paramaters)
    {
        var values = (object[])paramaters;
        var a = (string)values[0];
        var b = (string)values[1];

        MessageBox.Show(a);
        MessageBox.Show(b);
    }
```

However when I inspect Paramaters in the OnRegisterCommand call, they seem to be null.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: are all those methods part of your Class..? if so your Brackets don't seem to line up for starters.. make sure that the methods are part of that class

Comment: No, this is just the methods that are critical. TwoParamConverter is a separate class, ResigtrationViewModel is just the constructor that ties up the command, and OnRegisterCommand is the command being executed.

Comment: Are the parameters null or the values after the cast? Why are you casting? And isnt the converter only used to translate something from the viewmodel to something readable in the view.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //any checks and such things you can add yourself :)
    return new Tuple<string,string>((string)values[0],(string)values[1]);

    //or 
    //return values.ToArray()
}
```

Comment: here is a link why return values not work with multibinding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018436/icommand-parameters-always-null